# How to rendering an image using Jtable column Button rendering in a JTable?

Tags: java, jtable, image-rendering

How to add an image to a custom JTable row button, I have a JTable with a JButton in the fourth column and I want to put an image into fifth column using that button "Upload".

**Note: Button working as a file uploader.

Here is my image

[image]

Here is the code :

**NewFrame.java**

```
package test4;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;


public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        tablemodel();
    }
void tablemodel(){
    Color choices[] = { Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.white, Color.orange };
    ComboTableCellRenderer renderer = new ComboTableCellRenderer();
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(choices);
    comboBox.setRenderer(renderer);

    TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);

    TableModel model = new ColorTableModel();
    jTable1.setModel(model);
    TableColumn column = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
    column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    column.setCellEditor(editor);
    TableColumn column1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    column1.setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
     column1.setCellEditor(
        new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(27);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(90);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(90);

}
    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5", "Title 6"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(25, 160, 730, 275));

        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-795)/2, (screenSize.height-651)/2, 795, 651);
    }// </editor-fold>

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

  public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);

  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      value="Upload";

      if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
     // setText("dsda1");
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }
}

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
  //  button.setText("dsda2");
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

    if (isSelected) {
      button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());


    } else {
      button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getBackground());

    }
   label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    //label="DDD";
    button.setText("Upload");

    isPushed = true;
    return button;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    if (isPushed) {
      //
      JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
       System.out.println(label + "Uploaded Successfully!!");
    }
    isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);
  }

  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }
}
```

**ComboTableCellRenderer.java**

```
package test4;


import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

class ComboTableCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
  DefaultListCellRenderer listRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

  DefaultTableCellRenderer tableRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

  private void configureRenderer(JLabel renderer, Object value) {
    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Color)) {
      if (value.equals(Color.red)) {
            renderer.setText("0");
        } else if(value.equals(Color.orange)) {
            renderer.setText("10");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.yellow)) {
            renderer.setText("20");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.green)) {
            renderer.setText("30");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.white)) {
            renderer.setText("N/A");
        }
      renderer.setBackground((Color)value);
    } else {
      renderer.setText((String) value);
    }
  }

  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
      boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    listRenderer = (DefaultListCellRenderer) listRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
        index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    configureRenderer(listRenderer, value);
    return listRenderer;
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    tableRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) tableRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
        value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    configureRenderer(tableRenderer, value);
    return tableRenderer;
  }
}

class ColorTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

  Object rowData[][] = {
      { "1","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "2","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "3","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "4","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "5","","","","", Color.red, "30" }, };

  String columnNames[] = { "Index","Item","Reason","Image","Image 1","Marks","Allocated Marks" };

  public int getColumnCount() {
    return columnNames.length;
  }

  public String getColumnName(int column) {
    return columnNames[column];
  }

  public int getRowCount() {
    return rowData.length;
  }

  public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    return rowData[row][column];
  }

  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
    return (getValueAt(0, column).getClass());
  }

  public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
    rowData[row][column] = value;
  }

  public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
    return (column != 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way is to put a JLabel into the 5th column, and then add the image to the JLabel when the upload button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the answer.

PS : Full code typed in a one class.

This is the output image;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMcRz.jpg)

This is the code:

**Table.java**

```
package test5;

import com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.AbstractCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellEditor;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

/**
 *
 * @author Praneeth Thisal
 */
public class Table extends JFrame

{
    static javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
  static javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    static String orijinalpath="C:\\Users\\Praneeth Thisal\\Pictures\\JavaImages\\";
static String source;
static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    public Table() {
        Table1();
        tablemodel();
        loadframe();
    }

    void loadframe(){


    }
     void Table1()
    {
       jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                { "1","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "2","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "3","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "4","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "5","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "6","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
      { "7","","","","", Color.red, "30" },
            },
            new String [] {
                "Index","Item","Reason","Image","Image 1","Marks","Allocated Marks"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);
        jTable1.setRowHeight(80);

        getContentPane().add(jScrollPane1);

        java.awt.Dimension screenSize = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds((screenSize.width-795)/2, (screenSize.height-651)/2, 795, 651);
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(jTable1), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //frame.add(toolBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.pack();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });


    }
void tablemodel(){
 Color choices[] = { Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.green, Color.white, Color.orange };
    ComboTableCellRenderer renderer = new ComboTableCellRenderer();
    JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(choices);
    comboBox.setRenderer(renderer);

    TableCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);

//    TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
//    jTable1.getModel(model);
    TableColumn column = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(5);
    column.setCellRenderer(renderer);
    column.setCellEditor(editor);
    TableColumn column1 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3);
    column1.setCellRenderer(new ButtonRenderer());
//    TableColumn column2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
//    column2.setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());


     column1.setCellEditor(
        new ButtonEditor(new JCheckBox()));
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(27);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(120);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(100);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(90);
jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(90);



}
    class ComboTableCellRenderer implements ListCellRenderer, TableCellRenderer {
  DefaultListCellRenderer listRenderer = new DefaultListCellRenderer();

  DefaultTableCellRenderer tableRenderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();

  private void configureRenderer(JLabel renderer, Object value) {
    if ((value != null) && (value instanceof Color)) {
      if (value.equals(Color.red)) {
            renderer.setText("0");
        } else if(value.equals(Color.orange)) {
            renderer.setText("10");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.yellow)) {
            renderer.setText("20");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.green)) {
            renderer.setText("30");
        }
      else if(value.equals(Color.white)) {
            renderer.setText("N/A");
        }
      renderer.setBackground((Color)value);
    } else {
//     renderer.setText((String) value);
    }
  }

  public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index,
      boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    listRenderer = (DefaultListCellRenderer) listRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value,
        index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    configureRenderer(listRenderer, value);
    return listRenderer;
  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    tableRenderer = (DefaultTableCellRenderer) tableRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
        value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    configureRenderer(tableRenderer, value);
    return tableRenderer;
  }
}
//    class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer  {
//  JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
//int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
//  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(Table.orijinalpath+row+" Test.jpg").getImage().getScaledInstance(20, 20, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));
//
//  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
//      boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
////    lbl.setText((String) value);
//    lbl.setIcon(icon);
//    return lbl;
//  }
//}

class ButtonRenderer extends JButton implements TableCellRenderer {

  public ButtonRenderer() {
    setOpaque(true);

  }

  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      value="Upload";

      if (isSelected) {
      setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());
    } else {
      setForeground(table.getForeground());
      setBackground(UIManager.getColor("Button.background"));
     // setText("dsda1");
    }
    setText((value == null) ? "" : value.toString());
    return this;
  }
}

/**
 * @version 1.0 11/09/98
 */

class ButtonEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
  protected JButton button;

  private String label;

  private boolean isPushed;

  public ButtonEditor(JCheckBox checkBox) {
    super(checkBox);
    button = new JButton();
    button.setOpaque(true);
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        fireEditingStopped();
      }
    });
  }

  public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
      boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {

    if (isSelected) {
      button.setForeground(table.getSelectionForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getSelectionBackground());


    } else {
      button.setForeground(table.getForeground());
      button.setBackground(table.getBackground());

    }
   label = (value == null) ? "" : value.toString();
    //label="DDD";
    button.setText("Upload");

    isPushed = true;
    return button;
  }

  public Object getCellEditorValue() {

    if (isPushed) {
      //
      JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory());

        int returnValue = jfc.showOpenDialog(null);
        // int returnValue = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);

        if (returnValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File selectedFile = jfc.getSelectedFile();
            System.out.println(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                        Table.source=selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
        }

    //  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, label + ": Ouch!");
       System.out.println(label + "Uploaded Successfully!!");
    }
int row=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
     InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    try {
        String dest=Table.orijinalpath+row+" Test.jpg";
        is = new FileInputStream(Table.source);
        os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
    }   catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ButtonEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }   finally {
            try {
                is.close();
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ButtonEditor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
    }
       // Table nf = new Table();
    //nf.setVisible(true);

//    TableColumn column2 = jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4);
//    column2.setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
int j = jTable1.getRowCount();
int k=jTable1.getSelectedRow();
             ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Table.orijinalpath+row+" Test.jpg");
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setCellRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
            DefaultTableModel Tmodel=(DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
            jTable1.setRowHeight(80);
            Tmodel.setValueAt(icon, k, 4);



    for(int i=0;i<j;i++){
    jTable1.setColumnSelectionInterval(4, i);
      }


    isPushed = false;
    return new String(label);



  }

  public boolean stopCellEditing() {
    isPushed = false;
    return super.stopCellEditing();
  }

  protected void fireEditingStopped() {
    super.fireEditingStopped();
  }


    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                new Table();
            }
        });
    }
}

        class ImageRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
          JLabel lbl = new JLabel();
          public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
              ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(value.toString()).getImage().getScaledInstance(80, 60, Image.SCALE_DEFAULT));

             // System.out.println(value);
               lbl.setIcon(icon);
            return lbl;
          }
        }
```

Hope you all help this.
Thank you!